# Android - NestedScrollView jump when updating TextView's from LiveData observers

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I have a `NestedScrollView` which contains a view that is too large to fit on the screen (hence needing the scroll). There are various `TextView` elements that get updated fairly often (roughly every five seconds), and when they update the `NestedScrollView` scrolls to the top, completely forgetting where it was previously.

I have tried the solutions posted in "similar" questions, which primarily involve some version of the following:

- In the `TextView` set `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`
- In the parent layout (in my case, `ConstraintLayout`), set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

I have updated all of the relevant views to include these, but the view still scrolls to the top whenever the `TextView` elements are updated. Has anyone had any luck in fixing something like this?

Comment: Why don't you use ScrollView instead?

Comment: Same problem with ScrollView. The NestedScrollView is also necessary because the View is a child of a ViewPager2, which is a child of a collapsable bottom sheet.

Comment: has your `NestedScrollView` any id?

Comment: @Mohammad No, I don't have an ID on the `NestedScrollView`, I'll add that.

Comment: any changes? still, have the problem?

Comment: Yep, still have the issue.

Comment: Same here.. Did you find any solution?